# Failed to set (cornerRadius) user defined inspected property on (UIView)

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, interface-builder

### Details

I was watching the video of **Session 411 on WWDC 2014** referring to "**What's new on Interface Builder**", and I was trying out how to create Frameworks in order to make `@IBDesignable` classes to preview my changes in Storyboard without having to run the application.

`@IBInspectable` properties are showing correctly when I add my class to a specific view and are rendering the view correctly with the below code:

### Code

```
@IBDesignable
class MyView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor() {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var masksToBounds: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            layer.masksToBounds = masksToBounds
        }
    }
}
```

### Log

I noticed that these attributes were being added on **User Defined Runtime Attributes** (Under **Identity Inspector**). Now what I am expecting from this is when I run the code to keep these changed I made with a specific view.

I run the application and the view doesn't load the **User Defined Runtime Attributes**, and gives this error on output (not crash):

```
Unknown class MyClass in Interface Builder file
Failed to set (cornerRadius) user defined inspected property on (UIView)
```

### Question

What is causing the application not to load **User Defined Runtime Attributes** that I added under **Identity Inspector**?

Comment: something else would cause your problem, because that code works perfectly as it should be – the values are kept properly when I run the app. I can change all values under the standard _attributes inspector_ and under the _user defined runtime attributes_ section as well.

Comment: that is what I just said: _"the values are kept properly when I run the app"_, and you just said the same thing _"when I run the app the attributes that I added are working correctly"_, I'm sure about your problem here, maybe? (btw, I have not received any warning message on the console).

Comment: Have you added QuartzCore framework?

Comment: @holex I deleted the comment because I was unable to edit so I am writing here. I have added attributes on IB but they are not being loaded when application is running. This is what I meant.

Comment: @eridb, I understand you, but I can confirm and I tested your code and compiled a project, run the app, and the values are kept. if you'd like me to create a detailed answer what I experienced with adding screenshots, I can do it for you... but briefly, the values I have set in _IB_ are kept for the view when the project runs.

Comment: Interface Builder is complaining that the class associated with the view is not available in your target. MyClass.... Did you mean to configure it as "MyView" or is that a typo?

Comment: @holex I deleted Embedded framework and added new one. It gave an error on compiling complaining on iOS Target that minimum needs to be **iOS 8.0** (Mine was 7.0). Fixed it and runs well, but also gives output **failed to set user defined inspected property**.

Comment: @FergalRooney I don't know I deleted and created a new framework and that problem was fixed.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The code is correct.
When you declare a `@ IBDesignable` all the `@IBInspectable` properties are exposed to the Interface Builder as User Defined Runtime Attributes.

**The problem** -

> Unknown class MyClass in Interface Builder file

Is means that Interface Builder couldn't find some class. You have set wrong **class** that doesn't exist in your app.
Your customView class is **`MyView`** but in the Interface Builder you have **`MyClass`**

[image]

**Solution to fix**-

- Set correct class in interface Builder, in your case `MyView`
- Check **Designable** status. It should be *Up to date* , if it's not than something is wrong.

[image]

**Also** If you decided to remove customer Designable you should

- Remove custom class
- Remove User Defined Runtime Attributes

[image]

Comment: I would say, Simply remove and add class name again, and it should be working.

Answer (score 26):

Based on the question title, a few people may come here with a slightly different problem (like I did). If you

- added an @IBInspectible
- and then deleted it in code

Then you may also get an error similar to

> Failed to set (xxx) user defined inspected property on [Your Custom
>   View] ...: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   [xxx].

The solution is to delete the the old property.

[image]

Open the Identity inspector for your class, select the property name under User Defined Runtime Attributes, and press the minus button (-).

Again, this is not the answer to the OP's question, but it might be the answer to someone else's problem who comes here.

Comment: It didn't answer the OP's question but you are a wonderful human being for adding this answer because it fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

in Indentity inspector add in user Defined runtime attributes

`layer.cornerRadius` - type string

[image: first]

after go to Attibutes inspector and select "Clip Subviews"

[image: second]

Comment: it should be "Number" instead of "String" in "User Defined Runtime Attributes".